# Setup Windows 10 Taskbar like Macbook Menu Bar: No Window Allowed Under Taskbar

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar

A feature that I like about the menu bar on my MacBook is that it can remain visible always, and none of the windows for my apps would expand to lie under the menu bar.

I'd like to have that feature on my Windows computers. I'd like to maximize my windows so that they only expand up to the edge of the Windows taskbar and never go under the taskbar. I can't find anything in taskbar settings that might do this. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows will automatically do this if you set the taskbar to be Always on top.

But I just realized this option is an ancient option. I believe the taskbar is currently always on-top unless you set it to auto-hide.

If you set the taskbar to auto-hide, and then undo that change, it may fix the issue.

Comment: Yes, that did it. I turned auto-hide off. It took using a mac and small taskbar buttons for me to realize that was a useful feature.

Answer (score 2):

1. Right-click on an empty spot on the taskbar,
   click Taskbar settings option to open Taskbar settings page of the Settings app.
2. Here, turn off `Automatically hide the taskbar in desktop mode` option to show the Taskbar permanently.